# Property subscribe does not exist on type '(term:string) => Observable<any>'

Tags: javascript, angular, subscribe

I get the data from my server like so :

```
private allData(input:string): Observable<any> {
    let params = new HttpParams().set('q', input);
    return this.httpClient.get(Configuration.getData(url), { params: params });
}

public getDataService(){
    return this.dataService = (term: string) => this.allData(term);
}
```

and in my controller, i would like to check the status of the request above to execute a specific UI action. Here is how i subscribe my data :

```
this.getDataService().subscribe(
      res => this.httpData = res.results,
      err => console.warn(err),
      () => {
        this.loading.dismiss() /*close loader*/
      }
 )
```

I have this error :

> "Property subscribe does not exist on type  '(term:string) =>
>   Observable'"

Any help ?

Comment: From where `term` comes?

Comment: in my controller I added this:  this.dataService = (term: string) => this.allData(term);  term is what I get

Comment: From where you get `term`? Your `getDataService()` method is wierd to me.

Comment: I get the data in a Service called DataService and I call getDataService method in my home.ts controller. Even like this : this.DataService.getDataService().subscribe the error is still the same so it is due to the Observable

Comment: My getDataService works to feed a select input buttons in my home.html so I am sure, this method works.  i need to add "term" due to "input" here: let params = new HttpParams().set('q', input);

Comment: With his line  `this.dataService = (term: string) => this.allData(term);` you will make `this.dataService` to be lambda expression and later you will return that. It means `getDataService()` doesn't returns observable.

Comment: yes exactly. Is there a way to keep getDataService() method like this and make the subscribe possible to "fetch" the data and see if the http request is finished or ongoing ?

Comment: I cannot understand what you are trying but if you want to execute method to fetch data you have to do this: `this.getDataService()('some term').subscribe(...)`

Comment: thanks a lot, I can fetch the data and interrupt the loader when the data are ready